# Is there a type of Inheritance on F# Records

Tags: f#

I've just started with F# and using Record types as I am trying to move away from OOP to a more Functional programming approach.  The objects will ultimately be stored in MongoDB and used in the application.

I am moving my code from typescript and I have some objects that inherit from other objects.  Is that possible with record types or should I be using classes or structs?

Comment: For inheritance you need to use classes or interfaces. Records can implement interfaces, though I'm not trying to recommend you take that route. It's difficult to advice on how you should proceed with the port without detailed knowledge about the typescript source. General advice can be found [here](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/porting-to-csharp-intro/).

Comment: @BentTranberg , thanks for your reply.  I basically have 2 types of orders that share many properties ( about 80% ) and I am trying to use the DRY principle.

Comment: If you join us on F# Slack, it will be easier to keep long winded discussions going on issues like this, to help you with good architecture and F# in general. The Q&A format on SO is not that suitable for this kind of thing - it's more of a one-shot on particular problems that are common to all of us.

Answer (score 1):

No, F# records don't support subtype polymorphism (like classes in OOP land) nor structural subtyping (like various aspects of TypeScript).

If you must work with something that requires inheritance, you should generally use classes.

Comment: Thanks Phillip.  I guess I am looking for the best way to store similar types of objects ( Orders ) in MongoDB and be able to differentiate the order types in the code

Comment: Idea: Create a third record type that holds the common Order fields. You can then create two different Order types that each hold an instance of that third type.

Comment: Or you can use one Order record with a DU inside that copes with the differences. Might be easier with less matching everywhere.